# Sql MAX() Function rating movies

Tags: mysql

I have a moviedatabase with a list of movies, wich contains, title, release year, rating and so forth. I want to match all of my highest rated movies but the problem I get with the max() function is that it will only match just one of all my highest rated movies. So I would like to get all of my highest rated movies

For exemple this is want I get:

```
title    ||   max(rating)
Matrix           8
```

This is what I want:

```
title    ||   max(rating)
Matrix           8
Gladiator        8
X-Men            8
```

My code is:

```
SELECT title, max(rating)
FROM movies
ORDER BY rating DESC
```

Comment: You are lucky that you even got 'Matrix', being one of the top-rated titles. With your query you could have picked any title, no matter what rating. Reason: While you say which rating you want (the maximum), you don't say which title, so you just get a random title. (And then you sort the one aggregated record by a random rating :-)

Comment: Ah, ok I think I get it now. Thanks for helping me understand! :)

Answer (score 4):

Using subquery:

```
SELECT title, rating
FROM movies where rating = (select max(rating) from movies)
```

Comment: It might be a coincidence that `max(rating)` is 8 for all the movies. And if it differs then the answer will stand incorrect. I am not sure but my assumption :)

Comment: @RahulTripathi, are you sure? Can you elaborate?

Comment: As I said, I am not sure, just an assumption. :P(Actually got confused with this line `So I would like to get all of my highest rated movies`)

Comment: @RahulTripathi, you are not correct with your assumption. If all have 8, I will select 8 in subquery and will return all rows. If there are different ratings say(1, 5, 8) I will select 8 and then will select all where rating is 8. In Sql Server it is very easy with ordering, top and ties.

Comment: That makes sense. Got confused with the wordings ;) +1

Comment: It will return the movies that have rating equals to MAX(rating) aka 8. So I think that this what OP asks for.

Comment: Thanks very much for your solution! :) It was exactly what I wanted. I am only a beginner at this so its sometimes very hard to understand and explain to others. I am a little new to this use of subquery. If I understand it correctly it works kind of like if-statements in php coding?

Comment: @user3289402: No, it is the WHERE clause that is like an *if statement*, if you want to say so. The subquery is like a *function call*. So a record from the table matches the condition if its rating matches what the subquery returns. As the subquery returns the maximum rating found in the table, all records with that rating are found.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM movies
WHERE rating = (SELECT  max(rating)
                  FROM movies)
ORDER BY rating DESC
```